# Oracle PL/SQL: Create a short circuit query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm somewhat old school, so I call this short circuiting.

But I have 3 tables in Oracle.  I also have a "ProcessFlag."  If any of the data in the tables matches my criteria, I want to set the procesdFlag = 1.

I can obviously do this with if and else statements.

```
 select count(*) into myCounter from from Table1 where processflag = 1;
 if myCounter = 0 then
      select count(*) into myCounter from Table2 where processflag = 1;
      if myCounter = 0 then
           select count(*) into myCounter from Table3 where processflag = 1;
           if myCounter = 0 then
                 processFlag = 0;
           else
                 processFlag = 1;
           end if
      else
           processFlag = 1;
      end if
 else
       processFlag = 1;
 end if
```

So, Assuming I got all my if/eles's correct, I think you see what I'm trying to do.  If there is any row, in any table, that has the processFlag = 1, then I want to process.

This is just a small example for demonstration, but my real world has about 10 tables and I really don't want to have to nest if/else statements that deep if I don't need to.  And some of these tables have a lot of data, so if something is found in the 1st table, there is no need to check subsequent tables (which is why I called it short circuiting, because as soon as something is found, there is no need to process remaining code).

If there a cleaner/efficient way to do this in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case when` for short circuit query as following::

```
Select case 
when (select 1 from table1 where processflag = 1 and rownum =1) = 1 -- small table in terms of number of rows
then 1 
when (select 1 from table2 where processflag = 1 and rownum =1) = 1 -- larger than table1 table in terms of number of rows and so on
then 1
..
Else 0 end into processFlag
From dual;
```

`Case when` will stop execution of the statement once it finds one match.

Also you can give order of the table in the `case when` statement for Better performance, use small tables first and large tables at the end in `when` clause for good performance.

Cheers!!

Comment: Perfect!  That works.  It's a lot cleaner looking than what I had.  And also if the 8th or 9th query has a lot of rows it won't evaluate it!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
select . . .
from . . .
where exists (select 1 from table1 where processflag = 1) or
      exists (select 1 from table2 where processflag = 1) or
      exists (select 1 from table3 where processflag = 1) ;
```

That is, you can make your query conditional on a bunch of `exists` conditions.  You could use something similar to actually set a flag, if you are using PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *rownum*:

```
select count(*) into myCounter
from (
    select * from Table1 where processflag = 1
    ) l where rownum = 1;
```